# Java Check Balanced Parentheses

Tags: java

I need to write a program that checks if the parenthesis are balanced, which I understand how to do and have already implemented. But, there is a second part that I'm having trouble with, 
"Give an algorithm that returns the position in the string of the first offending parenthesis if the string is not properly nested and balanced That is, if an excess right parenthesis is found, return its position; if there are too many left parentheses, return the position of the first excess left parenthesis."

We haven't learned about stacks or regex so I can't utilize those. Below is my implementation to check if the nested parentheses are balanced.

```
public static int checkNest(char[] arr) {
    int counter = 0,index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == '(')
            counter++;
        else if(arr[i] == ')')
            counter--;
    }
    if(counter == 0)
        index = -1;
    return index;
}
```

Right now the incorrect index will always be 0, I need to manipulate my code to make the index of the incorrect parentheses correctly display.

Comment: You're now ready to perform a second pass... you need to start that pass with the information about which way it is unbalanced (that is, if the counter is less then 0 there are too many closing parens - it it's greater there are too many open parens).

Comment: ` counter--; if(counter<0){ return i;}` it  indicate that has more ) thatn (, so return the `i` that is the current position

Comment: Are you looking if exits open and close Parentheses ?

Comment: every time your `couner` is less then `0` - you are encountering an unbalanced parenthesis

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah I could do that but that'd only tell me which has more, I still need the index at which the problem initially presented itself.

Comment: Did you see the words "second pass"?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't quite sure at how that'd work though.

Comment: Are you sure that a balanced number of `(` and `)` is enough for you? Normally you want the right number of `(` *before* `)`. E.g. `")("` should not be a valid input.

Answer (score 0):

In general, case when you have multiple parentheses' types, you have to use `Stack`. You have only one mistake: you should keep counter and increase it when you find an open parenthesis and decrease when finding a close one. When the counter is negative at any step of iteration - then it's not balanced`.

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String str) {
    Deque<Character> stack = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (ch == '(' || ch == '[' || ch == '{')
            stack.push(ch);
        else {
            if (stack.isEmpty())
                return false;

            char prv = stack.pop();

            if (prv == '(' && ch != ')')
                return false;
            if (prv == '[' && ch != ']')
                return false;
            if (prv == '{' && ch != '}')
                return false;
        }
    }

    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

---

In case you have only one type of parentheses, then you could have only one counter:

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String str) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() && count >= 0; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '(')
            count++;
        else if (str.charAt(i) == ')')
            count--;
    }

    return count == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int checkNest(char[] arr) {
    int counter = 0,index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        // Only one incorrect parentheses. 
        index = i;
        if(arr[i] == '(')
            counter++;
        else if(arr[i] == ')')
            counter--;
    }
    if(counter == 0)
        index = -1;
    return index;
}
```

Comment: What about `)(` input?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  I think the question is asking the index of incorrect char.

Answer (score 0):

For an extra right parenthesis, you can immediately return the current value of `i` if the counter is zero, but for an extra left parenthesis, you must continue to parse the string until the end, so you must memorise the position of the last left parenthesis with `counter==0`:

```
public static int checkNest(char[] arr) {
    int counter = 0,index = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == '(') {
            if (counter == 0) {
                index = i;
            }
            counter++;
        } else if(arr[i] == ')') {
            if (counter == 0) {
                return i;
            }
            counter--;
        }
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return index;
}
```